# SQL: Using LIKE, return row if search matches any value in that row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-like

I'm trying to make a query where my LIKE can match any field in the row.

To put it another way, I don't want to explicitly set column names to match each LIKE condition.

So, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE any_field_value LIKE 'str%'
```

**NOT** like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col_a LIKE 'str%' OR col_b LIKE 'str%'
```

and so on.

Surely, not an uncommon request? Can someone show me the light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can only be done using dynamic SQL (unless using full text indexing).

Before you do that, I suggest reading: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) (assuming SQL Server)

Answer (score 2):

Actually that's simply not true. It can be done, assuming you have set up full text indexing.
Once again, assuming we're dealing with sql server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142488.aspx

I should point out, since it isn't very clear in the linked document, that you can specify * rather than column names in order to search all of the full text indexed columns in the table.

**EDIT:**
Full text search is available in mysql as well. It's not clear to me whether or not * can be used with it though.

Comment: Thanks @Telerian, I'm using MySQL...but since I don't know much (anything) about dynamic SQL or full text indexing, I'll just stick with the "can't do it easily" answer.  :)